# NoReverseMatch at /account/profile

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm getting the following error message when attempting to run a JS function and Ajax click call on a button press.

NoReverseMatch at /account/profile/
Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I know it's because the url, but i'm not sure what is incorrect with my url.

I also get the commented error message about a missing semicolon in my code when using a linting tool, but adding a comma seems to break the code.  If I change my url to just '/requestaccess/' i'll see the post in the console, but that view is not valid.

in the JS my var is defined as

```
                  var url = '{% url requestaccess %}';
```

in the ajax i'm attempting to call the url using:

```
                  $.ajax({
                      url: url,
                      data: JSON.stringify({ report_id: SelectedItems }),
                      dataType: 'json',
                      type: 'post',
                      success: function (data) {
```

The URL.py is setup as:

```
   url(r'^requestaccess/$', views.requestaccess, name='requestaccess')
```

My entire block of code is:

```
                  <script>
$(document).ready(function () {
                      var SelectedItems = [];
                      $('.checkbox').click(function () {
                          var SelectedItems = $(this).val();
                          var index = SelectedItems.indexOf(SelectedItems);
                          var url = '{% url requestaccess %}';
                          if (index == -1)
                          {
                            SelectedItems.push(SelectedItems);
                          }        else {
                            SelectedItems.splice(index, 1);
                          }
                        });

                      $('#submit-button').click(function (event) {
                          event.preventDefault();
                          $.ajax({
                              url: url,
                              data: JSON.stringify({ report_id: SelectedItems }),
                              dataType: 'json',
                              type: 'post',
                              success: function (data) {
                              }  //missing comma before closing curly brace
                            });
                        });
                    });
                  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using the URL tag put two quotes around the url name like this

```
var url = "{% url 'requestaccess' %}";
```

Done!

Comment: Doing that gives an unexpected token, expected error and the code doesn't run.

Comment: That worked, my profile page loads, but now my POST request never goes out.  I think it has something to do with the missing comma before closing curly brace, but adding one breaks the code.

Comment: do you see the url visited in the console when clicking? or any error raised??

Comment: Ignore that reponse, the POST goes through after i restarted the console.  I know the problem now, easy fix:  Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /account/requestaccess/
[15/Nov/2017 09:37:14] "POST /account/requestaccess/ HTTP/1.1" 403 2502

Comment: yeh use csrf_expemt